Hyperlink auto-adjust
I have a large sheets file with 30+ pages. In it, I have cells that are linked to other cells on various pages. If I add a line on one of the pages, is there a way to have the links on the other pages automatically adjust for the additional line, or do I have to do this manually each time?

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand a way to have the links on the other pages automatically adjust for the additional line. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By the way, from your tag, it seems that you are required to achieve your goal using Sheets API. In this case, what language do you want to use? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.
